# No module named pip - Python 3.9

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I normally do not use python, but needed it now. So I installed python 3.9 (on Ubuntu/WSL2 subsystem on Windows 10).

I need pip to. I thought it should be there by default (but it was not there):

> Starting with Python 3.4, it is included by default with the Python binary installers.
> (https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html)

So I went on to the next page (https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/). It told me to do

```
python -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

This did not work either. So I tested next instructions:

```
sudo wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

This failed with

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.command'

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a bug somewhere?

Comment: I haven't used it on WSL, but `apt install python3-pip` is what I've used previously. I don't know if WSL includes a package manager by default.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks. While waiting for the answer I found it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks, but please do not redirect people there. It does not at all answer my question. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a documentation error. I followed the instructions here and that worked:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239829/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-distutils-util